# Form validation using PHP and showing entered username in place hiding form input field

Tags: php, html

I want to validate username and password using php and then to show username in place of hiding the whole div field set, with in the same page.
I have taken form input fields inside field set and this all inside a div.

```
PHP:
<?php       //------------------------------------------------------------------------------>PHP VALIDATION
    $user="";
    $pass="";
    $nameErr="";
    $passErr="";`enter code here`
    //$pattern='/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_ ]*$/';
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {
        if(empty($_POST['uname']))
        {
            $nameErr='Enter Your Name!';
        }
        else
        {
            $user = test_input($_POST['uname']);
            if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/',$user))
            {
                $nameErr=' Re-Enter Your Name! Format Inccorrect!( only alpha, numbers,@_ are allowed)';
            }
        }
    }

    function test_input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>


HTML:

<div class='input'>
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $user;?>
        <form method='post' name='f1' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        User Name:<input type='text' id='uname' name='uname' class='uname' placeholder='USERNAME' autocomplete='off' autofocus><span class='error'>*</span>
                        Password:<input type='password' id='pass' class='pass' placeholder='PASSWORD' autocomplete='off'><input type='submit' name='submit' id='loggin' value='LOGIN' class='login'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <div class='errormsg' id='errmsg'><?php echo $nameErr;?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just echo the username instead of the input field. What is the problem in doing so?

Comment: Where is the **problematic** code? What is your desired output?

Comment: problem is i want to hide the form div and show the submitted user name after submit

Comment: There's like a million validation libraries and frameworks that contain validation libraries.

Comment: @AmitRatnakar That's not a problem, that's what you want to happen. Try and make it happen - if you can't, show us what you tried, and we'll help you out.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly easy construction. You'll need a form, a session (or some other container for the username) and some logic. See the sample code below. I think you can figure out the rest for yourself:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['btn_Login'])) {

        // validation code;

        // if validation succeeded:
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = $_POST['Username'];
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])) {

        echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['LoggedIn'];
?>
// display contents when logged in
<?php   
    } else { 
?>
// display form (where the field for the username is named 'Username' and the submitbutton is named 'btn_Login')
<?php   
}
```